# Unable to create bootable USB for windows xp installation

Tags: windows-xp, boot

I have mistakenly formatted windows xp partition of my hardrive while trying to install lubuntu operating system.
Now I can only have access to my computer through the live USB disk of lubuntu.

I have couple of .iso files of windows xp cd.
But when I tried to create bootable USB drive from it, it doesn't work.
It either shows "bootmgr is missing" message or it show a blinking cursor and nothing happens while booting.

The iso's that I have, contain all the necessary installation files required.

Is there a way to make USB drive boot from it?

I tried softwares like rufus but that too doesn't work with iso that I have.

Answer (score 0):

try to google a software called ultraiso, it can create an installation usb using an installation Windows cd or iso, no matter the Windows is xp or 7 or 8 or Windows Server.

If you can't find it in google, try to find it using another search engine such as www.baidu.com

then using the usb, you can install Windows again in your hard drive